# Smart pointers in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement smart pointers in doubly linked list (university task). Before that I've done the same task in pure C with raw pointers. 
The problem is when I add new Node to List by addNode() more than twice I have crash (I use CodeLite(g++), Windows 10 64bit). I assume that the problem is my memory management (destructors of Node and List). But I feel I don't have enough qualification to solve that. So any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Node       {

    T Value;
    weak_ptr<Node<T>> prev;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;

    ~Node() {
        while (next){
            prev = next->next;
            next.reset();
            next = prev.lock();
        }
    }

 };


template<typename T>
class List 
{public:  

     shared_ptr<Node<T>> start;
     weak_ptr<Node<T>> end;
     int size;

 public:
     List(): size(0){};
     ~List();

     void addNode (T value);

 };


template <typename T> List<T>::~List() 
 {   
     cout<<"List destructor"<<endl;
     while (start){
         auto sp = end.lock();
         end = start->next;
         start.reset(sp.get());
     }
 }

template <typename T> void List<T>::addNode(T value){
    Node<T>* nd = new Node<T>;

    if (size==0){
        start.reset(nd);
        start->Value = value;
        end = start;

    }

    else{
        auto sp = end.lock();
        auto sp2 = end.lock();
        sp->next.reset(nd);
        sp.reset(sp->next.get());
        sp->prev = sp2;
        sp->Value = value;
        cout<<"Value size is "<<size<<" "<<sp->Value<<endl;
        end = sp;

    }

    size++;
    return;
}




int main ()
{
 system("CLS");

  string a;
  string b;
  string c;

  a = "1 test";
  b = "2 test";
  c = "3 test";


  List<string> ls;
  ls.addNode(a);
  ls.addNode(b);
  ls.addNode(c);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: you don't need `shared_ptr` here. `unique_ptr` is the tool for the job if you want smart pointers.

Comment: What is this? `start.reset(sp.get());` and `sp.reset(sp->next.get());` this is completely wrong way to deal with smart pointers

Comment: @Slava there is only one owner for each node. The List object for the first node and the previous node for the rest. Ergo `unique_ptr` should be used.

Comment: @bolov this is double linked list, where `weak_ptr`   prev suppose to point to?

Comment: @Slava The correct tool for the job, with only one owner per node, is to use a `unique_ptr` for the owner and a raw pointer (yes, a raw pointer; it’s standard for non-owning) for the back link. Since this is a university assignment I give at most a 50% chance the prof. understands that raw non-owning pointers are what seems to be the standard now; if not, then both need to be smart pointers for the assignment, and `shared`/`weak` is the way to go.

Comment: If it stays in the Library Fundamentals v2, then [`observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) and `unique_ptr` will be the right solution going forward, but IIRC some people on the committee dislike `observer_ptr` and it might not make it to the final standard. I hope it does, just because then there’ll be a clear semantic distinction between “This is a raw pointer; it is from legacy code or code with a very weird ownership model, and we don’t know who owns it” and “This is a non-owning pointer”.

Comment: Good news! `list` already is a doubly linked list. Just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using smart pointers is automatic memory management, so your `List` and `Node` destructors not only badly implemented but also redundant. Just remove them (or make them empty). Your only task can be to implement `addNode()` properly:

```
template <typename T> void List<T>::addNode(T value){
    auto nd = std::make_shared<Node<T>>();
    nd->Value = value; // this should be done in Node constructor

    if (size++ == 0){
        start = nd;
    } else{
        auto sp = end.lock();
        nd->prev = sp;
        sp->next = nd;
    }
    end = nd;
}
```

When you deal with smart pointers normally you never call `reset()` and `get()` methods, only when you need to deal with raw pointers for various reasons (which is not the case here).

Note: as stated in the comment though empty destructors would work correctly there could be issue with long list due to recursive call so you may want to implement only `List` destructor to avoid that. Again this should be done without using `reset()` and `get()`, just working with smart pointers normally:

```
~List()
{
    while( start )
       start = start->next;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t actually work well for long lists, because it will destruct the nodes recursively instead of in a loop, using O(n) memory and possibly causing a stack overflow (the bad kind, not this site). To get around that, you need a custom destructor for the list, but it is fairly simple.

Comment: I doubt this solution would be used for long lists, obviously this is a homework exercise. Anyway such destructor can be added later when program implemented and works properly for small lists.

Comment: A simple test driver could be `int main() {List<int> l; for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { l.addNode(i); }; return 0; /* Check if it supports large lists */}`. I don’t know what course the OP is taking, or where, but if this were a homework assignment in one of my CS courses I’d be shocked if that weren’t one of the tests. (Note that I don’t know what most implementations’ stack size is and a million might not be enough, but it’s trivial to increase that number.)

Comment: @DanielH added List destructor

Comment: @Slava holy shit, it helped! Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me the good source about all this memory-managment theme in c++ especially about destructors?

Comment: @User88 any good C++ book should explain that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list